# jQuery Delay a click function for each element in matched set

Tags: jquery, click, timeout, delay

The following code is supposed to perform a click function on each element in the matching set delaying the click by 200ms before it takes effect on each element.

```
$('.panel').each(function(){
        window.setTimeout($('a.last').click(),pdel);
        pdel += 200;
    });
```

It all happens at the same time, the timeout function is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `pdel` was declared outside of the each.  But you'll want your `setTimeout` to use a function, otherwise you are passing the result of the `.click()` method to the `setTimeout`.

Try this:

```
var pdel = 0;
$('.panel').each(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('a.last').click();
    }, pdel);
    pdel += 200;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove window and reset the time function as a jQuery function:

```
var pdel = 0;
    $('.panel').each(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ $('a.last').click(); },pdel);
        pdel += 200;
    });
```

QED

Answer (score 0):

What does the $(".panel") have to do in this code? Is it about the amount of elements with class "panel"?

Just count the amount of $(".panels"):

```
var c = $(".panels").length;
var pdel = 200;
for(var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function() { /* your function */ }, pdel*c)
}
```

And do you really every 200ms want all `a.last`-elements to be clicked. Not just the one in the corresponding `.panel`? So the inner function would be:

```
function() { $(".panels").eq(c).find("a.last").click() }
```